# Async Await wth MongoDB c# driver

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb, wcf, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a auto completion textbox which connects to a mongodb server to get the collections from a database and look through it. My reference is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/argumentnullexceptionblogpost/archive/2013/06/21/an-rx-enabled-wpf-control-part-1-2.aspx).

```
Func<string, IObservable<Scrip[]>> getSuggestions = GetSuggestions;
```

GetSuggestions looks like

```
private IObservable<Scrip[]> GetSuggestions(string searchString)
    {
        return Observable.FromAsync(() => myService.SearchAsync(searchString));
    }
```

The Rx implementation looks like

```
var results = from searchTerm in textChangedObservable
            from serviceSuggestion in getSuggestions(searchString)
            select serviceSuggestion;

        results.ObserveOn(listBoxSearchResults).Subscribe(res =>
        {
            listBoxSearchResults.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var r in res)
            {
                listBoxSearchResults.Items.Add(r);
            }
        });
```

I am a bit stuck at how to implement this in my WCF service. I started off with a method

```
public async Task<List<Scrip>> Search(string searchString)
```

The implementation will be like

```
            var ret = await _database.ListCollectionsAsync(options);
```

Now how do i convert the return to `Task<List<Scrip>>` while keeping my method async?

Answer (score 0):

```
_database.ListCollectionsAsync(options);
```

This returns a Task.

If you remove `await` it will still be a Task.